Can't investigate the function $\log_e (x^2 + 1) - e^{-x} + 1$ further
I'm trying to investigate the monotonicity of the function $$f(x) = \log_e (x^2 + 1) - e^{-x} + 1.$$Thus, the first derivative yields $$f'(x)= \frac{2x}{1+x^2} + e^{-x}$$ After this, as it goes, I'm trying to find the critical points but can't find any due to a complicated equation so I choose to see it empirically instead. $e^{-x}$ is positive for all real $x$, while $\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$ is a proper fraction, it's sign being dependent on $x$. So, I can say that $f'(x)$ is positive for all $x>0$, but how do I determine its sign when $x<0$? How can I tell which expression in the function is bigger?

It turns out that, for each $x\in\Bbb R$, $f'(x)>0$. This is clear when $x\geqslant0$ (since then $\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\geqslant0$ and $e^{-x}>0$). On $(-\infty,0)$, $-e^{-x}$ is strictly increasing, whereas $\frac{2x}{x^2+1}$ decreases on $(-\infty,-1]$ and increases on $[-1,0)$. So, the minimal value that $\frac{2x}{x^2+1}$ takes on $(-\infty,-1]$ is the value attained at $-1$, which is $-1$. Therefore, on $(-\infty,-1]$, the minimal value of$$\frac{2x}{x^2+1}+e^{-x}\left(=\frac{2x}{x^2+1}-(-e^{-x})\right)$$is the value that it takes at $-1$, which is $-1+e>0$. Finally, on $(-1,0)$ you always have $\frac{2x}{x^2+1}>-1$ and $-e^{-x}<-1$, and therefore $\frac{2x}{x^2+1}+e^{-x}>0$.

[̵P̵S̵A̵]̵(̵h̵t̵t̵p̵s̵:̵/̵/̵i̵m̵g̵u̵r̵.̵c̵o̵m̵/̵a̵/̵Q̵O̵R̵P̵6̵B̵U̵)̵ ̵t̵h̵e̵ ̵m̵i̵n̵i̵m̵u̵m̵ ̵v̵a̵l̵u̵e̵ ̵y̵o̵u̵ ̵a̵r̵r̵i̵v̵e̵ ̵a̵t̵,̵ ̵a̵n̵d̵ ̵t̵h̵e̵ ̵a̵c̵t̵u̵a̵l̵ ̵m̵i̵n̵i̵m̵u̵m̵ ̵o̵f̵ ̵t̵h̵e̵ ̵f̵u̵n̵c̵t̵i̵o̵n̵ ̵d̵i̵f̵f̵e̵r̵.̵ ̵i̵ ̵c̵a̵n̵ ̵u̵n̵d̵e̵r̵s̵t̵a̵n̵d̵ ̵y̵o̵u̵r̵ ̵a̵n̵s̵w̵e̵r̵ ̵a̵n̵d̵ ̵i̵t̵ ̵m̵a̵k̵e̵s̵ ̵s̵e̵n̵s̵e̵.̵ ̵B̵u̵t̵ ̵I̵ ̵t̵h̵i̵n̵k̵ ̵y̵o̵u̵ ̵m̵i̵s̵w̵r̵o̵t̵e̵.̵ i understand now, you specified the interval, my apologies. thanks for the answer

Note that the function $\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$ obtains a global minima at $x=-1$ (where it is equal to $-1$). For every $x<0$, $e^{-x}>e^0=1$, therefore:
$$\frac{2x}{1+x^2}+e^{-x}>-1+1=0$$
so $f'(x)>0$ for every $x<0$.
